# How can I track eye movements with Google Video Intelligence API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I have a video with 3 persons speaking and I would like to annotate the location of people's eyes during it. I know that the Google Video Intelligence API has functionalities for object tracking, but it's possible to handle such an eye-tracking process using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Video Intelligence API represents [Face detection](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/feature-face-detection) feature, which gives you opportunity to perform face detection from within video frames as well as special face attributes.

In general, you need to adjust [FaceDetectionConfig](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1p3beta1/videos/annotate#facedetectionconfig) throughout `videos.annotate` [method](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1p3beta1/videos/annotate), supplying `includeBoundingBoxes` and `includeAttributes` arguments in JSON request body:

```
{
   "inputUri":"string",
   "inputContent":"string",
   "features":[
      "FACE_DETECTION"
   ],
   "videoContext":{
      "segments":[
         "object (VideoSegment)"
      ],
      "faceDetectionConfig":{
         "model":"string",
         "includeBoundingBoxes":"true",
         "includeAttributes":"true"
      }
   },
   "outputUri":"string",
   "locationId":"string"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed (Python) [example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-video-intelligence-python3) from Google on how to track objects and print out detected objects afterward. You could combine this with the [AIStreamer](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/streaming/live-object-tracking) live object tracking feature, to which you can upload a live video stream to get results back.

Some ideas/steps you could follow:

1. Recognize the eyes in the first frame of the video.
2. Set/highlight a box around the eyes you are tracking.
3. Track the eyes as an object in the next frames.